# What are the most expensive cards in Magic: The Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, pricing

I've heard of the Black Lotus and Dual Lands. Are there any other really expensive cards in Magic: The Gathering?

Comment: What do you mean by "really expensive"? Are you asking for the list of cards over a certain price? A list of the top N most expensive cards? Are we talking about the most expensive printing or the cheapest?

Comment: Either way would work. Most expensive printing (I imagine this will probably mean a lot of cards from Alpha and Beta).

Comment: Even then, it's not really going to be that simple. Magic cards don't exactly have a set or standardized price. It's just whatever price individual retailers are willing to sell or buy for.

Comment: For most cards you could probably say something reasonable based on a large number of recent sales but the most expensive cards are so rare that they don't get sold much so it's even harder to pin down the price.

Comment: I don't need prices, I just find it useful to know some of the more expensive ones because they often come up in conversation. I'm not looking to buy or sell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would probably be many cards from the very beginning of MTG. It was a special time in MTG. R&D was virtually non existent and there is a lot of cards that would never again see the light of day because of there ridiculous over powered nature. There is also the issue of the reserved list that ensures many of these cards scarcity.

If Star City Games prices are anything to go by here is a rough top ten. For arguments sake I use the Near Mint prices.

10) [Alpha Mana Vualt](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15246) - 800$

9) [Alpha Shivan Dragon](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15444) - 1000$

8) [Alpha Birds of Paradise](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=14823) - 1000$

7) [Alpha Time Vault](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15514) - 1500$

6) [Alpha Time Twister](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15520) - 2500$

5) Alpha ANBU Duals between 1500$ for a [Plateau](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15342) and 8000$ for a [Underground Sea](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15544)

4) Alpha Moxes between 3000$ for a [Mox Emerald](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15270) and 6000$ for a [Mox Sapphire](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15282).

3) [Alpha Time Walk](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=15517) - 4000$

2) [Alpha Ancestral Recall](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=14781) - 5000$

1) [Alpha Black Lotus](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=14829) - 20 000$

Comment: "9) Alpha Shivan Dragon - 1000$" - That's *adorable*!

Comment: Just note that these are near mint prices. A near mint Alpha card would be exceptionally rare as no one really took care of there magic cards in 1994.

Comment: True, but even so, "one of these things is not like the others", power level Wise.

Comment: I guess in the case of the dragon it is for people who remember an era of mtg where a dragon was worth more than duals.

Comment: All the others say "This is a necessary card to compete at the highest level of Vintage". Shivan Dragon says "He was my favourite when I was 12."

Comment: Casual appeal is actually a much higher driving force in mtg card prices than tournament viability. There is no reason to think Alpha cards are immune to this phenomena.

Comment: Really? Because the highs always seem to be tournament staples, especially the manabase.

Comment: To be clear, I love that someone loves Shivan Dragon that much.

Comment: No one needs Alpha cards to be competitive.  Beta 100% covers Alpha. Alpha just had a small run

Answer (score 10):

Here's one possibility for what you're looking for: [a search for all of the cards that TCGPlayer.com sells (directly or as a middleman) for at least $200](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/product/show?Price_Condition=Greater%20Than&Price=200&Type=Cards). At this time, it lists 64 cards in that range.

Answer (score 3):

The most expensive magic cards are:

Richard Garfield special occasions- these cards are special editions the Richard Garfield had printed for special occasions in his life.  They were really only given to friends and family.  They are so rare to even find one for sale is a ridiculous task.

Summer/Edgar magic Dual Lands(or anything summer magic)-  these Duals are insanely rare They can easily fetch $10,000 each for the blue ones.  Summer magic was a second print run of revised that had much better coloring.  however, there were so many print errors in the run that wizards decided not to ship it.  Luckily for us, a few cases got released to the public by mistake.  Blue hurricane is one card that came from this "set".  Basic islands from summer magic have been sold for $500.

Comment: Also, Artist proofs of The power 9 are more money than the playable cards.

Comment: you may want to edit that into your answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

The most expensive cards tend to be things that weren't intentionally released. WotC does test printing of cards and many of these have made it outside of the company and can be worth 10s of thousands of dollars.

There was a large test printing of 4th edition done by a different printer, many displays of these were retrieved from a dumpster at WotC and are available on the open market. They are referred to as Summer Magic and are hard to tell apart from the normal printing of the set. ABUgames have a Summer Tropical Island listed for $39,999. This is not a crazy price for these very rare and powerful cards.

Comment: Yes but are there really people who are willing to pay such a premium for a card that serves no greater practical purpose as the 250 dollar versions? Has there actually been a sale at such a price?

Comment: Yes, it is sort of "this is the price that it's *not* selling at."

Comment: Yes there are people who spend that much, when you see the player with archivist gloves and triple sleeved legacy deck has white bordered duals, you can assume they are Summer Magic ones. (Yes I've seen this)

Answer (score 0):

[Snapcaster Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snapcaster%20Mage) from Innistrad, It's not nearly as high as some of the other cards mentioned but it does come up frequently in conversation. I think last I checked the foil was over $100.

Comment: There are probably 100 foils that are higher priced than Snapcaster Mage

Comment: @LovesTha that's why in my post I said "It's not nearly as high as some of the other cards mentioned..." I mainly mentioned it because it does come up in conversation VERY frequently at least it does in my LGS.

Comment: This actually came up in a conversation yesterday, so thank you! I will +1 as soon as I get one more reputation.